# Android: Animations with fragment

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am trying to achieve iOS animation like below

[image]

I am trying to accomplish it with fragments. I want to push the current fragment to the back and slide in a new fragment from the bottom.

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pushback,R.anim.slideup,R.anim.pushback,R.anim.slideup);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, new FragmentTwo(), "MyStringIdentifierTag");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the desired animation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this two animations for the same

anim_slide_in_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@integer/anim_duration_long"/>
```

anim_slide_out_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_duration_long"/>
```

in your Activity

```
/**
     *
     * @param fragment Fragment to be replaced
     * @param shouldAnimate 1 to animating on showing fragment else 0
     */
    public void pushFragments(Fragment fragment,int shouldAnimate) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        if (shouldAnimate == 1) {
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_slide_in_top, R.anim.anim_slide_out_bottom);
        }
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```